# Calling tensor.packed_accessor32() throws memory error

Tags: c++, pytorch, libtorch

#### Problem Summary

Inside my main method, I create some tensors and pass them to the function `measure_distance_cuda`. From there, I try to create accessors to pass to a kernel that I've written (removed for minimal working example). However, when creating the accessors using `tensor.packed_accessor<>()` I get the following runtime error coming from TensorBase.h:

```
Exception has occurred: CPP/c10::Error
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF8071ECF19 in cuda_test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: c10::Error at memory location 0x0000004A42CFE4F0.
```

#### What I've tried:

My first thought was that memory errors are weird and can point to the wrong line, so I removed the call to the Cuda kernel that would actually use the accessors. So no indexing is occurring whatsoever. However, the error persists.

#### Minimal reproducible code

My main function:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <ATen/ATen.h>
#include <torch/types.h>

#include "raycast_cuda.cuh"

int main() {

    auto vert_options = at::TensorOptions().dtype(torch::kFloat64).device(torch::kCUDA);

    torch::Tensor vertices = torch::tensor(
        {{-1, 1, 0},
         {1, 1, 0},
         {-1, -1, 0}}, vert_options
    );

    at::Tensor distances = measure_distance_cuda(vertices);
    std::cout << distances << std::endl;
}
```

raycast_cuda.cu

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

#include <ATen/ATen.h>
#include <torch/types.h>

__host__
at::Tensor measure_distance_cuda(at::Tensor vertices) {

    // get return tensor and accessor ****NO ERROR HERE****
    at::TensorOptions return_tensor_options = at::TensorOptions().device(torch::kCUDA);
    at::Tensor distances = at::zeros({n_rays, n_faces}, return_tensor_options);
    at::PackedTensorAccessor32<float_t, 2> d_acc = distances.packed_accessor32<float_t, 2>();

    // get accessors for inputs ****ERROR HAPPENS HERE****
    at::PackedTensorAccessor32<float_t, 2> vert_acc = vertices.packed_accessor32<float_t, 2>()

    return distances;
}
```

**Some thoughts:**

- I noted that creating an accessor for the return values (`distances`) gives me no issues. It's only angry at me for trying it on the tensors I passed into the function. So I'm suspicious that I'm doing something in the wrong scope.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

I got a quick answer on the PyTorch forums... The answer was simple. I'm declaring my inputs as `kFloat64` which corresponds to `double_t` not `float_t`.

`auto vert_options = at::TensorOptions().dtype(torch::kFloat64).device(torch::kCUDA);`

should be

`auto vert_options = at::TensorOptions().dtype(torch::kFloat32).device(torch::kCUDA);`

so that I can call

`at::PackedTensorAccessor32<float_t, 2> vert_acc = vertices.packed_accessor32<float_t, 2>();`